# How does native code compiled with Android ndk toolchain interface with the Android OS?

Tags: android-ndk

I have a compiled C code for a game. I cross compiled it with arm compiler in ndk. Now I am trying to deploy it on my phone, which has the chip that is supported by the code, and get some functionality out of it but I do not know how. The only thing I have is an .img file, and as per the instructions, I put it on a separate partition of my Android phone. The code is supposed to interface with the Android OS. I am told I can create game moves, which are ARM ELF executables, and I have an Android.mk sample file. Can I leverage this file to get some functionality in the emulator perhaps? I have seen the Android.mk file to be used for building apps, and placing them in the /system directory. I have also successfully created an ndk project in Android Studio with the C code in JNI folder. My goad is basically to get a better understanding of how this game works, and how I can add my own moves, events, etc. to the game. How can I use the interfaces provided by the initial builder?

@Dan - The game came with a pdf. Please correct me if I am wrong. I should be able to put the C files or perhaps the .img file in the JNI folder, and then use System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary"); to reference it from my Main Activity? I also should be able to put a softlink in my /external folder to compile the code as part of the zImage; right? As far as putting it on a different partition, can I issue mount -o command from the global main make?

Comment: ... what instructions were you following that had you generate a partition image to use the NDK?

Comment: @user3326293, did you compile the C code with NDK? I compiled the code successfully but then i am transferring that code to `Virtual` device, it's giving `dlopen Failed` error. Although the libraries are in `jniLibs` folder. Any help about it?

Comment: Yes I did use NDK. I did not get the error you get. It should not make a difference, but I ran my code on my phone. Good luck; wish I could be of more help.